# Why did the samaras on my maple suddenly turn pink?

Tags: maple

I don't know a thing about Landscaping but have been getting more interested lately as I shop for houses.
Just last week I realized that a maple tree in my front yard had pink "helicopters" (now I know they are called "samaras").  I am nearly 100% certain that this tree has never had anything but green samaras before this year and it definitely has green leaves.  The tree is only around 20 feet tall, and I have lived in this house for over 20 years and never seen this.
Is it normal for the samaras to change color?

At the same time, there is a "red bud" tree that suddenly bloomed this year, when I am (again) nearly positive it has never been anything but green and brown.

Do trees often bloom and/or change seed colors like this?

With the Lilac bush in that same spot in the yard it's suddenly quite beautiful.

Answer (score 5):

This is pretty normal and could be a combination of weather / climate change.  For instance, this year we have had a much warmer winter season.  The "helicopter" in pink could be a nice photograph so enjoy it.

Comment: Yes the warm winters most of us have experienced have produced some odd results. Not just different timings, but lots of blossom, fruit, disease, etc. Things are different!